# Order of focusing of a elements in a Frame

Tags: java, swing

So far I have added this chunk of code

```
KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
KeyStroke tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0);
KeyStroke ctrlTab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
Set<KeyStroke> keys = new HashSet<>();
keys.add(enter);
keys.add(tab);

KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().setDefaultFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, keys);
```

It works; it adds enter and tab to the cycle of focus, but I want to change the order or selection. Currently its order is horizontal, but I want the cycle order to be vertical. How would I go about this?

I've tried to implement

```
public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot,
                         Component aComponent) {
    int idx = (order.indexOf(aComponent) + 1) % order.size();
    return order.get(idx);
}
```

...where `order` is a list of my elements. Now the focus is going vertical, but when it comes to focus on `jDateChooser`, it does't get focus.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score -1):

so i try to implement

```
public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot,
                         Component aComponent)
{
int idx = (order.indexOf(aComponent) + 1) % order.size();

return order.get(idx);
}
```

where order is a list of my elements, now focus is going vertically BUT when it comes to focus on jDateChooser it does't get focus.

What i need to set?

Comment: If you want to add more details to your question, then edit the question instead of posting a new answer.  I'll go ahead and incorporate it in there, but next time be sure to edit your question instead.